# Dynamically changing font color based on container values in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not too familiar with HTML/CSS and I have a UI model pointing to this HTML/CSS code.  I want to change the text color of 'Sample Text' below based on if the table value for let's say, when the #MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_value placeholder is empty or null.  Right now I have this, but it doesn't seem to be changing it to red when the table is empty.

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#MAP#PPOProspectTileViewDataForm tr[id$='_container']");
        var hasValue = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var row = rows[i];
            var valueSpan = row.querySelector("span[id$='_value']");
            if (valueSpan && valueSpan.innerText.trim() !== "") {
                hasValue = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        var headerLink = document.querySelector("#MAP#PPOProspectTileViewDataForm .bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer a");
        if (!hasValue) {
            headerLink.style.color = "#999999";
        }
    });
```

```css
##MAP#PPOProspectTileViewDataForm td {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.#MAP#BOLD {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.#MAP#CAPTION {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

##MAP#LOOKUPID_value {
  width: 80px;
}

##MAP#STATUS_value {
  width: 55px;
}

##MAP#MEMBERSHIPLEVELNAME_value {
  width: 180px;
}

.#MAP#DATATABLE {
  border-spacing: 2px 1px;
}

##MAP#ISPRIMARY_value {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

##MAP#ISPRIMARY_container,
##MAP#PRIMARYMEMBERLINK_container {
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 16px;
}

##MAP#STATUS_caption {
  padding-left: 7px;
}

a.#MAP#BOLD:empty {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="#MAP#PPOProspectTileViewDataForm">
  <div class="bbui-forms-fieldset-row">
    <div class="bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer">
      <a class="#MAP#BOLD">Sample Text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bbui-forms-fieldset-row">
    <table>
      <tr id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_container">
        <td class="#MAP#SHRINKCELL">
          <span id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer">
            <span id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_value"></span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="#MAP#PPOORGANIZATION_container">
        <td style="width: 300px;">
          <span id="#MAP#PPOORGANIZATION_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a id="#MAP#ORGLINK_action"><span id="#MAP#PPOORGANIZATION_value"></span></a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_container">
        <td>
          <span id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_container">
        <td>
          <a id="#MAP#PROSPECTASSIGNMENT_action"><span id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_value"></span></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: and where is the js of your code? your text color won't magically change with just this

Comment: A quick note: I highly recommend NOT using the # in your IDs/classes in HTML. That can get confusing as # is how you identify the ID in CSS selectors.

Comment: that an also ids are unique, you can't use the same id for multiple elements in your HTML

Comment: @ChrisG This is inherited code and the #placeholders tie back to a UI model that references this HTML form. It currently is working as intended without the introduction of what I tried to introduce change the color.  Basically if <span id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_value"></span> is empty, I want the color the 'Sample Text' to change

Comment: Your HTML is invalid since two elements have `id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_container"`

Comment: inherited or not, this is a horrible choice for `ids` and `classes`, and also nothing changes the fact that you can't have 2 o more elements  with the same id and third, you are yet to post your js but you used the js tag for your question

Comment: @ChrisG I added some JS to the post. I was originally trying that but took it out on my latest attempt.  As you can tell, a lot of this is guesswork on my end.  Regarding the two  id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_container", I just now noticed that.  The code works with that being duplicated (not sure why it is, that was leftover).  Would id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_container" being duplicated for whatever reason be a reason why the dynamic color change wouldn't work?

Comment: the code is probably working because is not doing anything with those elements with duplicated ids but if you want to reference those element by their id then your code won't work at all. Looking at your js now this line produces an error `var headerLink = document.querySelector("#MAP#PPOProspectTileViewDataForm .bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer a");` becuz it returns `null`

Comment: `var headerLink = document.querySelector("#MAP#PPOProspectTileViewDataForm .bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer a");` this line will never get you the element you want becuz of the invalid ids and classes in your HTML

Answer (score 2):

I refuse to go along with the pre-existing ID and CSS names on principle since it is SO bad to do so; AND produced invalid HTML.

Now to answer the question you can use the `:has` for example

```
#map-PPOProspectTileViewDataForm:has(#map-PPOINDIVIDUAL_value:empty) a.map-BOLD {
  color: red;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

```css
#map-PPOProspectTileViewDataForm td {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.map-BOLD {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.map-CAPTION {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#map-LOOKUPID_value {
  width: 80px;
}

#map-STATUS_value {
  width: 55px;
}

#map-MEMBERSHIPLEVELNAME_value {
  width: 180px;
}

.map-DATATABLE {
  border-spacing: 2px 1px;
}

#map-ISPRIMARY_value {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#map-ISPRIMARY_container,
#map-PRIMARYMEMBERLINK_container {
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 16px;
}

#map-STATUS_caption {
  padding-left: 7px;
}

#map-PPOProspectTileViewDataForm:has(#map-PPOINDIVIDUAL_value:empty) a.map-BOLD {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-PPOProspectTileViewDataForm">
  <div class="bbui-forms-fieldset-row">
    <div class="bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer">
      <a class="map-BOLD">Sample Text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bbui-forms-fieldset-row">
    <table>
      <tr id="map-PPOINDIVIDUAL_container">
        <td class="map-SHRINKCELL">
          <span id="map-PPOINDIVIDUAL_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer">
            <span id="map-PPOINDIVIDUAL_value"></span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="map-PPOORGANIZATION_container">
        <td style="width: 300px;">
          <span id="map-PPOORGANIZATION_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a id="map-ORGLINK_action"><span id="map-PPOORGANIZATION_value"></span></a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="map-garbage-1">
        <td>
          <span id="map-PPOTEAM_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="map-garbage-2">
        <td>
          <a id="map-PROSPECTASSIGNMENT_action"><span id="map-PPOTEAM_value"></span></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah. The `:has()` pseudo-class came to mind after seeing it used recently and I gave an answer using it. However, as I am just learning to use and implement it, I didn't think to go all the way up to the first common parent and I used an adjacent sibling combinator. Your example helped open my mind more and better understand ways that `:has()` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Using the existing invalid and confusing IDs/classes, you reference the span with getElementById and simply toggle a class on the anchor based on the length of the textContent of the span.

```js
const ppVal = document.getElementById("#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_value");
const headerLink = document.querySelector(".bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer a");
headerLink.classList.toggle("noVal",(ppVal.textContent.length == 0))
```

```css
##MAP#PPOProspectTileViewDataForm td {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.#MAP#BOLD {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.#MAP#CAPTION {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

##MAP#LOOKUPID_value {
  width: 80px;
}

##MAP#STATUS_value {
  width: 55px;
}

##MAP#MEMBERSHIPLEVELNAME_value {
  width: 180px;
}

.#MAP#DATATABLE {
  border-spacing: 2px 1px;
}

##MAP#ISPRIMARY_value {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

##MAP#ISPRIMARY_container,
##MAP#PRIMARYMEMBERLINK_container {
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 16px;
}

##MAP#STATUS_caption {
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.noVal{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="#MAP#PPOProspectTileViewDataForm">
  <div class="bbui-forms-fieldset-row">
    <div class="bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer">
      <a class="#MAP#BOLD">Sample Text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bbui-forms-fieldset-row">
    <table>
      <tr id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_container">
        <td class="#MAP#SHRINKCELL">
          <span id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer">
            <span id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_value"></span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="#MAP#PPOORGANIZATION_container">
        <td style="width: 300px;">
          <span id="#MAP#PPOORGANIZATION_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a id="#MAP#ORGLINK_action"><span id="#MAP#PPOORGANIZATION_value"></span></a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_container">
        <td>
          <span id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_container">
        <td>
          <a id="#MAP#PROSPECTASSIGNMENT_action"><span id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_value"></span></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I realized that Mark Schultheiss posted a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76508882/dynamically-changing-font-color-based-on-container-values-in-html-css/76509149#76509149) using `:has()` as I was composing this answer. I think he made a better and cleaner choice to use the pseudo-class on the first parent container that both targeted elements have in common rather than the first sibling. I don't want to copy his answer, but decided not to delete my lesser-experience answer because of the additional information that it contains. Perhaps this will help you better understand and implement Mark's answer.

---

First of all, I am going to assume that these IDs and class names are replaced with valid values through the UI model...

Second, your example is applying styling if the `a` with "sample text" itself is empty instead of when the intended `span` is empty. To achieve what you want, you can use the `:has()` pseudo-class on the parent element along with the `~` adjacent sibling combinator that matches the parent container of the empty `span` and then style the id of the `a`

`.bbui-forms-fieldset-row:has(~ .bbui-forms-fieldset-row ##MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_value:empty) .#MAP#BOLD`

[Can I use `:has()`?](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas()) is currently showing 87.43% browser support, which is leaving out Firefox users (2.63%). Though the [`has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class is supported by Firefox, it is not enabled by default. At present, Firefox users have to enable this in the settings.

Here is a barebones example (with a valid ID name) using `<span id="PPOINDIVIDUAL_value">` to show a working demonstration:

```css
.#MAP#BOLD {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bbui-forms-fieldset-row:has(~ .bbui-forms-fieldset-row #PPOINDIVIDUAL_value:empty) .\#MAP\#BOLD {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bbui-forms-fieldset-row">
  <a class="#MAP#BOLD">Sample Text</a>
</div>
<div class="bbui-forms-fieldset-row">
  <span id="PPOINDIVIDUAL_value"></span>
</div>
```

This example has this solution integrated into the code you provided:

```css
##MAP#PPOProspectTileViewDataForm td {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.#MAP#BOLD {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.#MAP#CAPTION {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

##MAP#LOOKUPID_value {
  width: 80px;
}

##MAP#STATUS_value {
  width: 55px;
}

##MAP#MEMBERSHIPLEVELNAME_value {
  width: 180px;
}

.#MAP#DATATABLE {
  border-spacing: 2px 1px;
}

##MAP#ISPRIMARY_value {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

##MAP#ISPRIMARY_container,
##MAP#PRIMARYMEMBERLINK_container {
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 16px;
}

##MAP#STATUS_caption {
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.bbui-forms-fieldset-row:has(~ .bbui-forms-fieldset-row id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_value":empty) .#MAP#BOLD {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="#MAP#PPOProspectTileViewDataForm">
  <div class="bbui-forms-fieldset-row">
    <div class="bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer">
      <a class="#MAP#BOLD">Sample Text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bbui-forms-fieldset-row">
    <table>
      <tr id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_container">
        <td class="#MAP#SHRINKCELL">
          <span id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="bbui-forms-summarytile-headerlinkcontainer">
            <span id="#MAP#PPOINDIVIDUAL_value"></span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="#MAP#PPOORGANIZATION_container">
        <td style="width: 300px;">
          <span id="#MAP#PPOORGANIZATION_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a id="#MAP#ORGLINK_action"><span id="#MAP#PPOORGANIZATION_value"></span></a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_container">
        <td>
          <span id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_caption" class="bbui-forms-summarytile-caption"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_container">
        <td>
          <a id="#MAP#PROSPECTASSIGNMENT_action"><span id="#MAP#PPOTEAM_value"></span></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the code is autogenerated from the UI model and the UI model passes the values through.  I ran this code in and nothing seemed to have changed.  I wonder if there is some style attribute within the software that is not allowing this to override.

Comment: @Cwnova This worked for me in testing only when I substituted valid ID and class name values. I'll add a working example to my answer. Actually, I just realized that I didn't remove all of my testing values, so I will add a basic working example and an integrated example. Additionally, I forgot to mention the browser support for `has()`.

Comment: @Cwnova You can use the browser's Developer Tools to see what the output is and what rules are being applied.